# In RUBY CSV - how do I sum 1 column of sorted csv data and make sureto keep the constraints or limit on the data

Tags: ruby, csv

I am working on a csv reader, and looking to do manipulations on the data, I would like to sum one column - years, but make sure to not go past a certain number of points - say 1 million. I am not able to sum the columns, it is incrementing it. My constraint is 10 + years only

The csv looks like this

```
id, numbers, years,
1, 50000, 10
2, 40000, 12  
3, 50000, 9
```

My ruby file looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pry'
require 'rubygems'
require 'fastercsv'

mycsv = CSV.read('input.csv', headers:true, col_sep: ', ', header_converters: :symbol, converters: :integer) # read the entire file into a 'loans' variable


new_mycsv = mycsv.find_all do |p|
 p[:years].between?(10, 12)
end

puts new_mycsv.inspect

#Sum csv data on first row
new_mycsv.first << "SUM"


new_mycsv[1..-1].each{|row| row << row.inject(:+)}

CSV.open("output.csv","w") do |out|
    new_mycsv.sort_by { |row| each do |row| }
   p out << row
 end
end
```

Comment: It will be good if you can paste a expected output of the input you have. Your question is not clear.

Comment: I would like to add the column "numbers" , based on "years" - excluding data from "years" that I don't need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running you code as posted :

```
$ ruby -w t_op.rb 
t_op.rb:23: warning: shadowing outer local variable - row
t_op.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected '}'
    new_mycsv.sort_by { |row| each do |row| }
                                             ^
t_op.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
```

Some comments to your code :

- post error-free code, so that we can copy-paste and work on it
- post only the code necessary to answer your question. For example

  ```
  require 'pry'
  ```

  is unused and not necessary to solve the posted problem
- run ruby with the -w option and correct all warnings
- this statement :

  ```
  new_mycsv.first << "SUM"
  ```

  concatenates `"SUM"` to the first element of `new_mycsv`, resulting in changing the array to :

  ```
  1,50000,10,SUM
  2,40000,12
  ```
- this statement :

  ```
  new_mycsv[1..-1].each{|row| row << row.inject(:+)}
  ```

  ignores the first row and concatenates something to other rows, resulting in changing the array to :

  ```
  1,50000,10
  2,40000,12,"[:id, 2, :numbers, 40000, :years, 12]"
  ```

Here is one solution (I'm not sure if I have well understood what `not go past a certain number of points` means) :

```
require 'csv'

mycsv = CSV.read('input.csv', headers:true, col_sep: ', ', header_converters: :symbol, converters: :integer) # read the entire file into a 'loans' variable

new_mycsv = mycsv.find_all { | row | row[:years].between?(10, 12) }

puts '---- new_mycsv'
puts new_mycsv

puts '---- selecting rows until the limit of numbers is reached'
numbers_limit  = 100_000
sum_of_numbers = 0
mycsv_limited  = []

new_mycsv.each do | row |
    number = row[:numbers]
    puts "row[:numbers]=#{number}  sum_of_numbers=#{sum_of_numbers}"
    break if sum_of_numbers + number >= numbers_limit
    sum_of_numbers += number
    puts "sum_of_numbers=#{sum_of_numbers}"
    mycsv_limited << row
end

CSV.open("output.csv","w") do |out|
    mycsv_limited.sort_by{ | row | row[:numbers] }.each { | row | out.puts row }
end
```

File input.csv :

```
id, numbers, years,
1, 50000, 10
2, 40000, 12  
3, 50000, 9
4, 50000, 11
5, 40000, 11
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
---- new_mycsv
1,50000,10
2,40000,12
4,50000,11
5,40000,11
---- selecting rows until the limit of numbers is reached
row[:numbers]=50000  sum_of_numbers=0
sum_of_numbers=50000
row[:numbers]=40000  sum_of_numbers=50000
sum_of_numbers=90000
row[:numbers]=50000  sum_of_numbers=90000
```

File output.csv :

```
2,40000,12
1,50000,10
```